# How to deserialize a Json Array into different Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

i'm trying to deserialize a json string into a new list on C# using json.net.

When i do a direct deserialization i get some attributes as null because i have different objects on my list.

So i want to create a "translator" for that task, building generic objects and setting the attributes of my objects.

this is my progress..

```
CitasProfesorWeb.JavaService.AgendaWSService service =
    new JavaService.AgendaWSService();
JsonTextReader reader;

private void cargaDatos()
{
    String lista = service.obtenerCitasNuevas(2);
    reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(lista));

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //here i want to read the attributes or objects
    }
}
```

i have tried using JsonConvert.PopulateObject(reader,cita) but i'm getting an error message saying that i have invalid parameters.

--Edit--

This is the string that i'm receiving :

```
[{"idCita":6,"fechaSolicitud":"2012/4/20","fechaCita":"2012/4/19","horario":{"idHorario":1,"fechaInicio":"2012/1/16","fechaHoy":1337281297199,"fechaFin":"2012/5/30","nombre":"Enero-Mayo 2012","profesor":{"idProfesor":2, "nombre":"Guillermo", "apellido":"Salazar", "nomUsuario":"g.salazar", "email":"g.salazar@itson.mx", "ubicacion":"LV323", "descripcion":"Profesor Interino"}},"alumno":{"idAlumno":1, "nombre":"Jhonatan", "apellido":"Romero", "nomUsuario":" jromero", "email":"jhonatanromgggggh", "carrera":"LSIA" },"asunto":"asesorias","status":"0","horaCita":"10:0"}, {"idCita":7,"fechaSolicitud":"2012/4/20","fechaCita":"2012/4/27","horario":{"idHorario":1,"fechaInicio":"2012/1/16","fechaHoy":1337281297199,"fechaFin":"2012/5/30","nombre":"Enero-Mayo 2012","profesor":{"idProfesor":2, "nombre":"Guillermo", "apellido":"Salazar", "nomUsuario":"g.salazar", "email":"g.salazar@itson.mx", "ubicacion":"LV323", "descripcion":"Profesor Interino"}},"alumno":{"idAlumno":1, "nombre":"Jhonatan", "apellido":"Romero", "nomUsuario":" jromero", "email":"jhonatanromgggggh", "carrera":"LSIA" },"asunto":"asesorias","status":"0","horaCita":"11:0"}, {"idCita":11,"fechaSolicitud":"2012/4/20","fechaCita":"2012/4/20","horario":{"idHorario":1,"fechaInicio":"2012/1/16","fechaHoy":1337281297199,"fechaFin":"2012/5/30","nombre":"Enero-Mayo 2012","profesor":{"idProfesor":2, "nombre":"Guillermo", "apellido":"Salazar", "nomUsuario":"g.salazar", "email":"g.salazar@itson.mx", "ubicacion":"LV323", "descripcion":"Profesor Interino"}},"alumno":{"idAlumno":1, "nombre":"Jhonatan", "apellido":"Romero", "nomUsuario":" jromero", "email":"jhonatanromgggggh", "carrera":"LSIA" },"asunto":"asesorias","status":"0","horaCita":"17:0"}, {"idCita":12,"fechaSolicitud":"2012/4/27","fechaCita":"2012/5/3","horario":{"idHorario":1,"fechaInicio":"2012/1/16","fechaHoy":1337281297199,"fechaFin":"2012/5/30","nombre":"Enero-Mayo 2012","profesor":{"idProfesor":2, "nombre":"Guillermo", "apellido":"Salazar", "nomUsuario":"g.salazar", "email":"g.salazar@itson.mx", "ubicacion":"LV323", "descripcion":"Profesor Interino"}},"alumno":{"idAlumno":1, "nombre":"Jhonatan", "apellido":"Romero", "nomUsuario":" jromero", "email":"jhonatanromgggggh", "carrera":"LSIA" },"asunto":"tesis","status":"0","horaCita":"12:0"}, {"idCita":15,"fechaSolicitud":"2012/5/11","fechaCita":"2012/4/20","horario":{"idHorario":1,"fechaInicio":"2012/1/16","fechaHoy":1337281297200,"fechaFin":"2012/5/30","nombre":"Enero-Mayo 2012","profesor":{"idProfesor":2, "nombre":"Guillermo", "apellido":"Salazar", "nomUsuario":"g.salazar", "email":"g.salazar@itson.mx", "ubicacion":"LV323", "descripcion":"Profesor Interino"}},"alumno":{"idAlumno":1, "nombre":"Jhonatan", "apellido":"Romero", "nomUsuario":" jromero", "email":"jhonatanromgggggh", "carrera":"LSIA" },"asunto":"Tesis","status":"0","horaCita":"10:0"}]
```

This is my class:

```
public class Cita
    {
        Profesor profesor;

        public Profesor Profesor
        {
            get { return profesor; }
            set { profesor = value; }
        }

        Alumno alumno;

        public Alumno Alumno
        {
            get { return alumno; }
            set { alumno = value; }
        }

        DateTime inicioCita;

        public DateTime InicioCita
        {
            get { return inicioCita; }
            set { inicioCita = value; }
        }

        String asunto;

        public String Asunto
        {
            get { return asunto; }
            set { asunto = value; }
        }

        String lugar;

        public String Lugar
        {
            get { return lugar; }
            set { lugar = value; }
        }

        int status;

        public int Status
        {
            get { return status; }
            set { status = value; }
        }

        DateTime fechaSolicitud;

        public DateTime FechaSolicitud
        {
            get { return fechaSolicitud; }
            set { fechaSolicitud = value; }
        }


    }
```

Comment: as comment, i'm very new using Json, i made some test deserializing simple objects, but on this json object i have objects nested

Comment: Can you post your class and json string?

Comment: i just updated my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `dynamic` to parse your json string like below (without the need to declare `cita`,`horario`,`profesor`,`alumno` classes)

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (var cita in dynObj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
        cita.horario.profesor.apellido,
        cita.alumno.nombre,
        cita.fechaSolicitud
        );
}
```

Comment: I will give a try :), appears to be a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic class for converting JSON to objects (be sure to include `System.Web.Script.Serialization`)

```
    public static T JsonToObject<T>(string JsonData)
    {
        // Deserialize the JSON into the object
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        T rf = (T)jss.Deserialize(JsonData, typeof(T));

        return rf;
    }
```

To convert an object back to JSON, use this general class

```
    public static string ObjectToJson<T>(T rf)
    {
        // Serialize the object as JSON
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jss.Serialize(rf, sb);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

As an example of usage, you would use

```
        string json = @"[{""idCita"":6,""fechaSolicitud"":""2012/4/20"",""fechaCita"":""2012/4/19"",""horario"":{""idHorario"":1,""fechaInicio"":""2012/1/16"",""fechaHoy"":1337281297199,""fechaFin"":""2012/5/30"",""nombre"":""Enero-Mayo 2012"",""profesor"":{""idProfesor"":2, ""nombre"":""Guillermo"", ""apellido"":""Salazar"", ""nomUsuario"":""g.salazar"", ""email"":""g.salazar@itson.mx"", ""ubicacion"":""LV323"", ""descripcion"":""Profesor Interino""}},""alumno"":{""idAlumno"":1, ""nombre"":""Jhonatan"", ""apellido"":""Romero"", ""nomUsuario"":"" jromero"", ""email"":""jhonatanromgggggh"", ""carrera"":""LSIA"" },""asunto"":""asesorias"",""status"":""0"",""horaCita"":""10:0""}, {""idCita"":7,""fechaSolicitud"":""2012/4/20"",""fechaCita"":""2012/4/27"",""horario"":{""idHorario"":1,""fechaInicio"":""2012/1/16"",""fechaHoy"":1337281297199,""fechaFin"":""2012/5/30"",""nombre"":""Enero-Mayo 2012"",""profesor"":{""idProfesor"":2, ""nombre"":""Guillermo"", ""apellido"":""Salazar"", ""nomUsuario"":""g.salazar"", ""email"":""g.salazar@itson.mx"", ""ubicacion"":""LV323"", ""descripcion"":""Profesor Interino""}},""alumno"":{""idAlumno"":1, ""nombre"":""Jhonatan"", ""apellido"":""Romero"", ""nomUsuario"":"" jromero"", ""email"":""jhonatanromgggggh"", ""carrera"":""LSIA"" },""asunto"":""asesorias"",""status"":""0"",""horaCita"":""11:0""}, {""idCita"":11,""fechaSolicitud"":""2012/4/20"",""fechaCita"":""2012/4/20"",""horario"":{""idHorario"":1,""fechaInicio"":""2012/1/16"",""fechaHoy"":1337281297199,""fechaFin"":""2012/5/30"",""nombre"":""Enero-Mayo 2012"",""profesor"":{""idProfesor"":2, ""nombre"":""Guillermo"", ""apellido"":""Salazar"", ""nomUsuario"":""g.salazar"", ""email"":""g.salazar@itson.mx"", ""ubicacion"":""LV323"", ""descripcion"":""Profesor Interino""}},""alumno"":{""idAlumno"":1, ""nombre"":""Jhonatan"", ""apellido"":""Romero"", ""nomUsuario"":"" jromero"", ""email"":""jhonatanromgggggh"", ""carrera"":""LSIA"" },""asunto"":""asesorias"",""status"":""0"",""horaCita"":""17:0""}, {""idCita"":12,""fechaSolicitud"":""2012/4/27"",""fechaCita"":""2012/5/3"",""horario"":{""idHorario"":1,""fechaInicio"":""2012/1/16"",""fechaHoy"":1337281297199,""fechaFin"":""2012/5/30"",""nombre"":""Enero-Mayo 2012"",""profesor"":{""idProfesor"":2, ""nombre"":""Guillermo"", ""apellido"":""Salazar"", ""nomUsuario"":""g.salazar"", ""email"":""g.salazar@itson.mx"", ""ubicacion"":""LV323"", ""descripcion"":""Profesor Interino""}},""alumno"":{""idAlumno"":1, ""nombre"":""Jhonatan"", ""apellido"":""Romero"", ""nomUsuario"":"" jromero"", ""email"":""jhonatanromgggggh"", ""carrera"":""LSIA"" },""asunto"":""tesis"",""status"":""0"",""horaCita"":""12:0""}, {""idCita"":15,""fechaSolicitud"":""2012/5/11"",""fechaCita"":""2012/4/20"",""horario"":{""idHorario"":1,""fechaInicio"":""2012/1/16"",""fechaHoy"":1337281297200,""fechaFin"":""2012/5/30"",""nombre"":""Enero-Mayo 2012"",""profesor"":{""idProfesor"":2, ""nombre"":""Guillermo"", ""apellido"":""Salazar"", ""nomUsuario"":""g.salazar"", ""email"":""g.salazar@itson.mx"", ""ubicacion"":""LV323"", ""descripcion"":""Profesor Interino""}},""alumno"":{""idAlumno"":1, ""nombre"":""Jhonatan"", ""apellido"":""Romero"", ""nomUsuario"":"" jromero"", ""email"":""jhonatanromgggggh"", ""carrera"":""LSIA"" },""asunto"":""Tesis"",""status"":""0"",""horaCita"":""10:0""}]";
        List<Cita> p = JsonToObject<List<Cita>>(json);
```

**EDIT:** You specifically mentioned JSON.NET, so the above code may not help you if you want to keep with that.  But, to parse all the attributes of a JSON string, you will need a class that matches the JSON response string.  From there, you can set attributes of other objects as necessary.

Comment: The problem using the direct deserialization is the json responce that doesn't match with my Class and are marked as null, so i need to extract the atributes and make the set for each object

Comment: @rafuru Your best course of action is to design an object that matches the JSON string, then break it out into other objects as necessary.

Comment: i know but the client wants over all things follow his UML class diagram.. so i must to adjust -_-